# Use memset for 2d array at specific row

Tags: c++, memset

recently, I have learnt about `C++`. Specially, I learned about `memset` function. But I don't know how to set value for **2d array** at specific row

Example:

```cpp
int dp[10][10];

// I want to set all values for dp[0] by using memset
// I can do it, by using For loop, like 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    dp[0][i] = 1000;
```

I have tried this

```cpp
memset(dp[0], 1000, sizeof dp[0]);
```

But it's not working well.

So I want to know if there are any ways to use memset like what I hope? Thanks :D

Comment: Why would you use `memset` for that? With optimizations enabled, compilers will turn the loop and `memset` into the same assembly. You could also use `std::array< std::array<int, 10>, 10>` instead of a C array to make it easier.

Comment: You cannot use `memset()`, to address bigger chunks than single bytes values. What you have there is already the fastest possible way to initialize that array with some value different from `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do such a thing because *memset* write bytes.
For instance `memset( dp[0],3,sizeof( dp[0] )) ;` will write bytes == 3 in all 10 ints of dp[0].
So `dp[i] == 0x03030303` for *i* in *0..9* !

Answer (score 3):

The correct function is `std::fill_n`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n

```
std::fill_n(std::begin(dp[0]), sizeof dp[0] / sizeof dp[0][0], 1000);
```

or C++17 or later:

```
std::fill_n(std::begin(dp[0]), std::size(dp[0]), 1000);
```

`std::fill` is also possible: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill

```
std::fill(std::begin(dp[0]), std::end(dp[0]), 1000);
```

I would do it like that:

```
for (auto &i : dp[0]) i = 1000;
```

It is also the shortest version.

Comment: Or even better use `std::array` to begin with.